# Java Paths: Build and absolute path

Tags: java, java-io, java.nio.file

Currently, I'm getting an absolute path using `"/" +` approach, I don't feel confortable with.

```
Paths.get("/" + someFolder, this.backOfficeProperties.getMassivePendingLocation());
```

I guess there has to be another more elegant approach to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: "...I don't feel confortable with.": for what reason?

Comment: Have you had a look at the Path type in java?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about being platform dependent than you can use **`File.separator`** which will be `\` or `/` depending on what system you run the software on.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically find out the root of the file system, rather than assuming it's `"/" (UNIX)` by using

```
File.listRoots()
```